# Get filesize and filename of flowfiles as flow file contents

Tags: apache-nifi

I need to fetch the file size and file name of each flow file and append them to flow file content.

The flow file is of parquet data and it contains some data which I dont need but I want to get filename,filesize as flowfile contents.

the file size is listed in DETAILS tab of flow file but it in not in attributes. If possible can I map that to attributes TAB.

[image]

I want to get the File Size to be captured in content.

Comment: what is the original content of the files? what is the expected result? please edit your question and add more details.

Comment: your request sounds wired to me. adding filesize into a file will change filesize. filesize and filename are the standard attributes of the flow file. why do you want to add those attributed into file content?